# joomla 2.5 saving multiple select lists?

Tags: joomla, selectlist, multiple-select

I'm trying to add a multiple select list to my backend component, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried searching the joomla forums and have tried what they've suggested, but it still doesn't work.

Here is what I have done:

/models/fields/categories.php

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $item->id, $item->title);
};
$drawField  = '';
$drawField .= '<select name="'.$this->name.'" id="'.$this->name.'" class="inputbox" size="10" multiple="multiple">';
$drawField .= JHtml::_('select.options', $options, 'value', 'text', $strVal, true);
$drawField .= '</select>';
return $drawField;
```

/models/forms/edit.xml

```
<field name="catid" type="categories" multiple="true" size="40" class="inputbox" label="COM_PRODUCTS_FORM_LBL_EDIT_CATID" description="COM_PRODUCTS_FORM_DESC_EDIT_CATID" required="true" filter="safehtml" />
```

/models/edit.php

```
protected function loadFormData()
{
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_products.edit.edit.data', array());
    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = $this->getItem();
        $data->catid = explode(',',$data->catid);
    }
return $data;
}
```

/tables/edit.php

```
public function check() {
    if (property_exists($this, 'ordering') && $this->id == 0) {
        $this->ordering = self::getNextOrder();
    }
    $this->catid = implode(',',$this->catid);   
return parent::check();
}
```

It saves the field catid as "Array" in the backend. Yet when I put in manually 143,148 as the field value, it doesn't highlight those fields, so obviously my implode/explode aren't working.. Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok figured it out.. The issue was this: filter="safehtml" in the xml file if anyone else is having issues with the same thing... All is good now :)